# Grails foreign domain not fetching records and throwing out of memory exception

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I was trying to fetch the records for secondary domain i.e. Vehicle Details Domain which is associated to Vehicle domain.

Following is my domain classes.

```
class MRVehicle {

    String make
    String brand
    String model
    String versione
    String plateNumber

    MRVehicleDetail vehicleDetail

    static hasOne = [vehicleDetail : MRVehicleDetail]

    static mapping = {

        sort("id")
        cache true

        table name: "parco_veicoli"//, schema: "public"
        id generator:'sequence', params:[sequence:'parco_veicoli_seq']
        id column: "id", sqlType: "int4"

        model column: "modello"
        brand column: "marca"
        versione column: "versione"
        plateNumber column: "targa"
        vehicleDetail cascade: 'all',fetch: 'join',unique: true

        version false
    }
}
```

and

```
class MRVehicleDetail {

    Double vanMaxLengthExtVehicle
    Double vanMaxWidthExtVehicle
    Double vanMaxHeighExtVehicle
    Double vanMaxLengthIntLoadComp
    MRVehicle parco

    static mapping = {
        table name: "vehicle_detail"//, schema: "public"
        id column: "id", sqlType: "int4" , generator: 'foreign', params: [property: 'parco']
        parco column: 'id', insertable: false, updateable: false , sqlType: "int4"

        vanMaxLengthExtVehicle column: "van_max_length_ext_vehicle"
        vanMaxWidthExtVehicle column: "van_max_width_ext_vehicle"
        vanMaxHeighExtVehicle column: "van_max_heigh_ext_vehicle"
        vanMaxLengthIntLoadComp column: "van_max_length_int_load_comp"
        version false
    }
}
```

If I try to fetch vehicle detail instance on my GSP page something like:-

```
${MRvehicle.vehicleDetail.vanMaxLengthExtVehicle}
```

while executing the above line I am getting out of memory exception.

Comment: You are calling the class `MRvehicle` in your gsp and asking the class to return all of its objects or some form of its objects - you have missed out a few layers, you need to query lookup and return results - as a test in a gsp this should really be  `${MRvehicle?.findAll()?.vehicleDetail.vanMaxLengthExtVehicle}`

Comment: For me MRVehicle is the vehicle class object which i am fetching in my controller class and render trying to render its properties in gsp